How to unit test FromSqlInterpolated in EF Core?
I want to write a unit test for a method that returns data from a stored procedure, how do I mock this?
// Arrange
var mockDBContext = new Mock<MyDBContext>(options);
var mockData = await GetData();

mockDBContext.Setup(x => x.GetDataFromStoredProcedure(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(mockData);

Example of method that I want to test
public async Task<List<MyModel>> GetDataFromStoredProcedure(int Id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await MyModel.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC {MyStoredProcedure} {Id}").ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}


As you are mocking the GetDataFromStoredProcedure, you are not testing it

How do I mock the result of FromSqlInterpolated?

the GetDataFromStoredProcedure does not contain any logic except retrieving data . so if you mock the FromSqlInterpolated you don't have anything to test

@user24640939 the method that needs mocking is GetDataFromStoredProcedure, which you already mocked. That means MyModel.FromSqlInterpolated will never be called. mockDbContext.GetDataFromStoredProcedure will always return mockData

so how do I test the stored procedure execution, sonarcloud shows the stored procedure execution line as not covered
